# Formulário responde Ocorreu um erro ao enviar a mensagem!

Tags: php, formulário, post, envio-de-email

Criei um formulário que no ambiente de homologação está respondendo e indo para página de destino de agradecimento. Quando subo ao servidor do domínio ele está respondendo negativamente. Alguém me diz onde estou errando?

```js
<?php

 /* Valores recebidos do formulário  */
 $nome = $_POST['nome'];
 $email = $_POST['email']; // Email que será respondido
 $empresa = $_POST['empresa']; 
 $fone = $_POST['fone'];
 $opcoes = $_POST['opcoes'];
 $escolha = $_POST['escolha'];
 $produto = $_POST['produto'];
 $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
 
/* Destinatário e remetente - EDITAR SOMENTE ESTE BLOCO DO CÓDIGO */
$to = "";
$to = "";
$remetente = ""; // Deve ser um email válido do domínio
 
/* Cabeçalho da mensagem  */
$boundary = "XYZ-" . date("dmYis") . "-ZYX";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers.= "From: $remetente\n";
$headers.= "Reply-To: $email\n";
$headers.= "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";  
$headers.= "$boundary\n"; 

/* Layout da mensagem  */
$corpo_mensagem = " 
<br>Formulário via site
<br>--------------------------------------------<br>
<br><strong>NOME:</strong> $nome
<br><strong>EMAIL:</strong> $email
<br><strong>EMPRESA:</strong> $empresa
<br><strong>TELEFONE:</strong> $fone
<br><strong>SEGMENTO:</strong> $opcoes
<br><strong>ONDE NOS CONHECEU:</strong> $escolha
<br><strong>INTERESSE NO PRODUTO:</strong> $produto
<br><strong>MENSAGEM:</strong> $mensagem

<br><br>--------------------------------------------
";

 
/* Função que envia a mensagem  */
if(mail($to, $nome, $mensagem, $headers))
{
 echo "<script>
 location= './obrigado.html';
 </script>";
 
} 
 else
 {
  echo "<br><br><center><b><font color='red'>Ocorreu um erro ao enviar a mensagem!";
}
?>
```

```html
  <!-- Contact Form -->                            
                         <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-sm-6 mb-40">
                         <form class="contact-form" action="contact.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                         <div class="cf-left-col">
                                        
                                        <!-- Name -->
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="nome" id="name" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Nome" pattern=".{3,100}" required>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <!-- Empresa -->
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="empresa" id="company" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Empresa" pattern=".{3,100}" required>
                                        </div>

                                                                                
                                        <!--Form Choice-->
                                        
                                        <div class= "mb-20 mb-md-10">                                        
                                        <select class="input-md round form-control" name="opcoes" id="select" placeholder="Segmento" pattern=".{3,100}">
                                        <option value="">Segmento</option>                               
                                        <option value="Adm de Cartões">Adm de Cartões</option>
                                        <option value="Atacado">Atacado</option>
                                        <option value="Banco/Financeiras">Banco/Financeiras</option>
                                        <option value="Cobrança">Cobrança</option>
                                        <option value="E-Commerce">E-Commerce</option>
                                        <option value="Indústria">Indústria</option>
                                        <option value="Seguradora">Seguradora</option>
                                        <option value="Serviços">Serviços</option>
                                        <option value="Utilities">Utilities</option>
                                        <option value="Varejo">Varejo</option>
                                        <option value="Outros">Outros</option>
                                    </select>
                                    </div></div>
                                    
                         <div class="cf-right-col">
                                                                                
                                         <!-- Email -->
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Email" pattern=".{5,100}" required>
                                        </div>

                                        <!-- Telefone -->
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="fone" id="phone" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Telefone" pattern=".{3,100}" required>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <!--Form Choice2-->
                                       
                                        <div class= "mb-30 mb-md-10">                                        
                                        <select class="input-md round form-control" id="00Ni000000A7cey" name="escolha">
                                        <option value="">Onde nos conheceu</option>
                                        <option value="Anúncio">Anúncio</option>
                                        <option value="Evento/Feira">Evento/Feira</option>
                                        <option value="Indicação">Indicação</option>
                                        <option value="Sites de Busca">Sites de Busca</option>
                                        <option value="Outros">Outros</option>
                                        </select>
                                        </div></div>
     
      <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" id="00Ni000000A7tt7" name="produto" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Interesse no produto" pattern=".{3,100}" >
                                        </div> 
                                        
                                        <!-- Message -->
                                        <div class="form-group">                                            
                                        <textarea name="mensagem" id="message" class="input-md round form-control" style="height: 158px;" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <!-- Send Button -->
                                        <div class="align-right">
                                        <button class="submit_btn btn btn-mod btn-medium btn-round" id="submit_btn">Enviar Mensagem</button>
                                        </div>
                                      
                                <div id="result"></div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
  </div>
                
                </div></div></div>
            
            <!-- End Contact Section -->
```

Comment: qual erro que dá ?

Comment: Exatamente este: else
 {
  echo "<br><br><center><b><font color='red'>Ocorreu um erro ao enviar a mensagem!";
}

Comment: @Bulfaitelo o código php não encaminha para a página de agradecimento e o email não é enviado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(mail($to, $nome, $mensagem, $headers))
{
    echo "<script>
    location= './obrigado.html';
    </script>";

} 
    else
    {
        echo "<br><br><center><b><font color='red'>Ocorreu um erro ao enviar a mensagem!";
}
```

O que está a aconter é que a função `mail($to, $nome, $mensagem, $headers)` está a dar erro logo vai para o else. Verifique os parâmetros que passa para lá para ver se está tudo correcto.